# Add quotes or anything else around selected text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

There is a shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to add HTML tags around selected text, but is there a shortcut for adding any extra text, not tags. For example quotes.

Thanks.

Comment: Just select the text you want to quote and add the quote you want (`"`, `'`) or any kind of brakets (`()`, `[]`, `{}`)

Comment: This question is too broad as it is written. For text wrapping, ST uses macros. There are built in macros for brackets, quotes, and html tags. There are packages that add wrapping for other languages. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?